# Parent / Child components VUE.JS 2.1.6 data passing

Tags: javascript, components, vuejs2

I'm very confused about how to properly tie components together.
I have two components registered globally:

```
Vue.component('product-welcome-component', {
    template: '#product-welcome-template',
    props: ['showModal'],
    onCreate(){
        showModal = false;
    } 

});

Vue.component('product-create-modal-component', {
    template: '#create-modal-template'   
});
```

In the parent's template I included the child component like this:

```
<template id="product-welcome-template">
<div class="welcome-wrapper">
    <div class="purpose-title"><h1 class="welcome-text">Welcome to Product Hub</h1></div>
    <div class="purpose-create-btn"><button  @@click="showModal = true" class="btn btn-primary btn-success create-btn">Create New Product</button></div>
<product-create-modal-component v-if="showModal"></product-create-modal-component>
</div>
 </template>
```

The problem is (one of them) is that my create-modal-component is always showing, regardless of the value of showModal, in fact i can put in v-if="1 === 2" it would still show.

I'm sure this is not the right way of registering parent / child components but I can't seem to find a proper example. Mostly what i see that the parent is the app instance and it has a child of 'child' component and then they can communicate.

I have a feeling that including the child component in the parent's template is bad practice as it makes the parent strongly coupled.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by  including the child component in the parent's template?

Comment: I meant something like this
Parent template:
<div><child></child></div>

Answer (score 0):

You are having `showModal` as props to `product-welcome-component`, but you are trying to set it false in created, but you have to use `this` in `created` to access `showModal`, like following:

```
Vue.component('product-welcome-component', {
    template: '#product-welcome-template',
    props: ['showModal'],
    onCreate(){
        this.showModal = false;
    } 

});
```

However you are saying `product-create-modal-component` shows even you do `v-if="1 === 2"`, which should not be the case  Can you create a fiddle of your case.

Comment: I will do so once i get back to work, I managed to get around my problem for now by having components only talk with the vue instance, but I would really like them being able to just communicate between each other via events and props. THe documentation is not very helpful on the site.